# how to check service bus topic empty or not c#

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I wonder is there any way to check `service bus topic empty or not`

I tried with nuget `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` and below sample code.

In this nuget I do not get `ITopicClient` :(

```
 var topicClient =  TopicClient(); // we can not create object
            var topicPeek = topicClient.Peek();
            TopicDescription topicDescription = new TopicDescription(topicName);
            var topicSize = topicDescription.SizeInBytes;
```

any way to do so?

Comment: Why do you need that info? Remember that checking message counts via NamespaceManager is both slow and not necessarily accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` package, you can create instances of Service Bus clients by using [MessagingFactory.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagingfactory?view=azure-dotnet) to get a reference to a `MessagingFactory`. Once you have one of those, you can call `CreateTopicClient` to get a `TopicClient` instance.

(Note that there's also a newer package called `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` that's a bit limited in functionality, but it supports .NET Core. If you use that package, the class hierarchy is somewhat different, and you can create instances of the clients directly.)

Comment: Got exception - `Missing authorization token,`

Comment: What exactly are you doing to get the connection string?